# Ho do I update property bag items in SPFX extensions?

Tags: rest, spfx, pnpjs, property-bag

I want to update Property Bag items with pnp-core js. I can get the property bag items by the following code -

pnp.sp.web.select('AllProperties').expand('AllProperties').get()

But what is the code to update Property Bag items?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, you should be able to leverage the **processQuery** rest endpoint, and perform a query like the one below, in order to update a **site custom property bag**:

```
    import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse, ISPHttpClientOptions } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
    [...]
    let myPropertyBag ="customPropbag1"
    let myNewPropBagValue ="new value"
    let clientServiceUrl = `${this.siteAbsoluteUrl}/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery`;
    let data = `<Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName="Javascript Library"><Actions><ObjectPath Id="1" ObjectPathId="0" /><ObjectPath Id="3" ObjectPathId="2" /><ObjectPath Id="5" ObjectPathId="4" /><Method Name="SetFieldValue" Id="6" ObjectPathId="4"><Parameters><Parameter Type="String">${myPropertyBag}</Parameter><Parameter Type="Number">${myNewPropBagValue}</Parameter></Parameters></Method><Method Name="Update" Id="7" ObjectPathId="2" /><Query Id="8" ObjectPathId="2"><Query SelectAllProperties="true"><Properties /></Query></Query><Query Id="9" ObjectPathId="4"><Query SelectAllProperties="true"><Properties><Property Name="edrms_eFolderId" ScalarProperty="true" /></Properties></Query></Query></Actions><ObjectPaths><StaticProperty Id="0" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current" /><Property Id="2" ParentId="0" Name="Web" /><Property Id="4" ParentId="2" Name="AllProperties" /></ObjectPaths></Request>`;
    let httpPostOptions = {
            headers: {
              'accept': 'application/json',
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'X-RequestDigest': this.formDigest
            },
            body: data
          };

    let serviceResponse: SPHttpClientResponse = await this.spHttpClient.post(clientServiceUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, httpPostOptions);
[...]
```

and then

```
let serviceJSONResponse: Array<any> = await serviceResponse.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, property bags are read-only in RESP API, so it's not possible right now, as the ideology of PnP JS Core is to be a wrapper around REST API only.
JSOM API should be used instead now for writing to property bags.